# Django: Renew and set JWTs as HttpOnly cookie using a middleware. Response() returning django.template.response.ContentNotRenderedError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, cookie-httponly

I have a custom middleware where I am adding **SimpleJWR** `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` to every authorized requests as I am using `HttpOnly` cookies. Also here I have added code to check whether an `access` token is valid or not. If not, then a request is sent using `requests` which fetches the new `access` token and set's it as `HttpOnly` cookie. So far, I'm able to get the new `access` token after it expires. But, the url from where I dispatched the request returns this error:

```
raise ContentNotRenderedError(
django.template.response.ContentNotRenderedError: The response content must be rendered before it can be accessed.
```

At the first request it works. It returns the response and saves the tokens as `HttpOnly` cookies but after the token expires and if I again make the request, instead of (what I want to happen) saving the tokens as `HttpOnly` cookies and returning the same response again, it is returning the error.

I think the issue is in the `response` statements. My middleware:

```
import jwt
import datetime
import requests
import json

from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.conf import settings

class AuthorizationHeaderMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response=None):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        access_token = request.COOKIES.get('access')
        refesh_token = request.COOKIES.get('refresh')
        print(refesh_token)
        # check if the access token is valid
        # if not, send new access token to cookie
        if access_token:
            key = settings.SECRET_KEY
        try:
            decoded_access_token = jwt.decode(access_token, key, algorithms=["HS256"])
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            # Signature has expired
            print("expired; sending for new token")
            url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/refresh/'
            data = {"refresh": refesh_token}
            resp = requests.post(
                url, 
                data=json.dumps(data),
                headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
                )
            result = resp.json()
            new_access_token = result['access']
            response = Response()
            response.set_cookie('access', new_access_token, httponly=True)
            response.set_cookie('set', 'new')
            return response

            request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = f'Bearer {access_token}'
        return self.get_response(request)
```

How is this error coming and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def __call__(self, request):
    access_token = request.COOKIES.get('access')
    refesh_token = request.COOKIES.get('refresh')
    print(refesh_token)
    # check if the access token is valid
    # if not, send new access token to cookie
    if access_token is not None:
        key = settings.SECRET_KEY
    else:
        return Response({"Error" : "No token found"})
    try:
        decoded_access_token = jwt.decode(access_token, key, algorithms=["HS256"])
        request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = f'Bearer {access_token}'
        return self.get_response(request)
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        # Signature has expired
        print("expired; sending for new token")
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/refresh/'
        data = {"refresh": refesh_token}
        resp = requests.post(
            url, 
            data=json.dumps(data),
            headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
            )
        result = resp.json()
        new_access_token = result['access']
        response = Response()
        response.set_cookie('access', new_access_token, httponly=True)
        response.set_cookie('set', 'new')
        request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = f'Bearer {new_access_token}'
        
        return self.get_response(request)
```

Comment: After adding these I got these error: `if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: Because if `access_token` not found in cookie at that time `access_token` return `None`.and our condition is not satisfy. so  `__call__` method not return any response.I edited my ans.

Comment: Another way you can set and get httponly cookie.Check this :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66248320/14131913) and see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63622625/14131913 or https://github.com/HarryAustin/tweeter-DrfTest-httonlycookie/blob/main/Django_Rest_Framework/middleware.py